# Eclipse-generated method parameters having unreasonable names

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, parameters, naming

I am sometimes running in the problem that when I use the Eclipse function to add/generate methods of an interface which I want to implement the parameter names of these methods are just "too generic".

So, if it is a String parameter it is named paramString, if it is a int it is called paramInt and so forth - instead of being called something that expresses the parameters' semantics.

For instance, I am currently implementing the javax.portlet.PortletSession interface (part of the JSR 286 spec.; I need a custom implementation).

Methods carry parameters like these:

```
public void setAttribute(String paramString, Object paramObject) 
public void setAttribute(String paramString, Object paramObject, int paramInt)
```

What I would like to have is sth like this:

```
public void setAttribute(String key, Object value) 
public void setAttribute(String key, Object value, int scope)
```

Sometimes the generation of methods works the way I want, sometimes, just as this time, it doesn't. I assume this has to do with the way I import the library holding the interface I want to implement, but maybe someone can explain the behavior in a bit more detail?

Maybe someone can give an explaination along a concrete example:
How would I have to import the JSR 286 spec, how to generate the methods to get what I want?

Thank you so much!

Comment: So, here is what I did: I downloaded the JSR 286 spec. and imported the source into Eclipse. Then I referenced the source instead of the JAR containing the class files only. That did the trick - not sure if there is another way, but it seems as if you need the sources - at least in this case here.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a way to regenerate all method signatures for a bunch of classes? Otherwise I have to do this change manually know which would be pretty annoying :(

Answer (score 1):

Simply rename the parameters yourself. I suspect the parameter names are generated based on the information Eclipse has to work with - if the parameter name isn't present in the jar file, it can't provide it. If there's a debug version of the portlet jar file, or if you can tell Eclipse where the JavaDoc is, that might help... but ultimately, it's simple enough to just rename them manually, most of the time.

Just as a test, I suspect that if you declare a variable of type `PortletSession` and then try to use it with auto-complete, like this:

```
PortletSession session = null; // Doesn't matter for this
session.set <hit ctrl-space here>
```

My guess is that this *won't* include the parameter names in the auto-complete... whereas in situations where the auto-implement works, it will. It's all about how much information Eclipse has to work with.

Comment: To be honest, I like my approach with importing the source more than doing it handish.

Comment: @user1090608: Sure, where you can that's better - but I'd view getting the JavaDoc etc as more relevant there than just the auto-generated parameter names.